# What is equivalence class for 'Mage_Core_Helper_Http' and 'Mage_Core_Helper_Data' in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

In Magento 1, I can have `return Mage::helper('core')`  which is object of `Mage_Core_Helper_Data`. I wonder what the equivalent class for **Magento 2**.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.
In Magento 2, the Helper class can be defined as

```
    class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
    {
        public function __construct(
          \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     ){
           parent::__construct($context);
      }
    }
```

If you want to get Mage::helper('core'), then you just define a public function in this class,

```
    class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
    {
       public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
       ){
          parent::__construct($context);
       }

       public function getCoreHelper()
       {
          return $this;
       } 
    }
```

If you want to get "Mage::helper('core/helper')" like in Magento 1, you just need to use the automatic constructor dependency injection:

```
    class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
    {
       protected $httpHelper;

       public function __construct(
          \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
          \Magento\Framework\App\Http $httpHelper
       ){
          parent::__construct($context);
          $this->httpHelper = $httpHelper;
       }

       public function getCoreHelper()
       {
          return $this;
       } 
       public function getHttpHelper()
       {
          return $this->httpHelper;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanting to know which helper class to extend from in order to create your own helper class, it is: `\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have this question because I have been rewriting some M1 modules to M2. In M1, there are  some codes just directly uses Mage::helper('core') and Mage::helper('core/http') to implement some functionalities.

Comment: My pleasure. In Magento 2, they have done a much better job of sticking to the Single-Responsibility doctrine. Essentially, each php class has one job. Bc of this, you will find yourself instantiating many more classes as needed. Additionally, since you are in the process of converting modules, you should read about Composition over Inheritance. In layman's terms, try to stay away from abstraction as much as possible. Become familiar with that now and it will benefit you throughout your career.

Comment: @JeffYu please don’t forget to mark this answer as accepted if you feel it satisfactorily answered your question. Thanks!